# Zend Select particular set of columns from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

Given a query :

```
SELECT t1.c1, t2.c1 FROM t1,t2;
```

How to write it in Zend framework without using joins ?

Comment: I don't see how you can select columns from more than one table without using any kind of join (whatever the type), no matter whether you use Zend framework or not.

Comment: You can do it without using a `JOIN` statement, but what field do they have in common?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below join query in zend framework,

```
    $sql = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select();

    $sql->join('table2', "table1.column1 = table2.column1", array(column1,column2), 'inner');
```

Comment: OP specified `without using joins`... But it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Well I guess .. the above query that I wrote works fine in Mysql without join. So why it has to use join to run it in Zend framework ?

Comment: @user3341158 The fact that you didn't actually type `JOIN` in your query doesn't mean you don't use a join. In this case it's a `FULL OUTER JOIN` (carthesian product), but still a join.

Comment: oh.... yes .. I missed it .... thanks dude .. so  I need to use join .. to make it work inside zend framework

Comment: @user3341158 I guess you could also run your query as raw, like `$db->query('SELECT t1.c1, t2.c1 FROM t1,t2')`, but this has absolutely no advantage over a regular `joinCross` method.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a common field (we'll call it `c2`), you can do something approximating a `JOIN` without actually doing a `JOIN`.

```
// we'll assume $adapter is an instance of Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli

$cols = $adapter->fetchAll(
    '
        SELECT
            t1.c1 AS t1c1,
            t2.c1 AS t2c1
        FROM t1, t2
        WHERE t1.c2 = t2.c2
    '
);
```

Using `Zend_Db_Select` you can do it this way

```
$rows = $adapter->select()
    ->from('t1', array('t1c1' => 'c1'))
    ->from('t2', array('t2c1' => 'c1'))
    ->where('t1.c2 = t2.c2')
    ->query()->fetchAll();
```